# Jquery Errors due to updating wordpress 3.5

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've updated WordPress to 3.5 and getting error, J-query is not working.
I have reviewed wordpress 3.5 master list and tried debugger script but it did not work.
Having this error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined).

Information about Error:

1). Having error in Chrome, firefox, safari, internet explorer.
2). SCRIPT_DEBUG (define;) did not fix the error.
3). J-query error
4). Location of the file: /themes/****/library/includes And file name is image_uploader.php And line number is 769.

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined

```
function goToIndexforsave() { 


document.getElementById('sorted_successmsg_div').innerHTML = 'processing ...';
var img_save_url = 'http://www.holidayvillas4hire.com/index.php?page=sort_image&pid='+document.getElementById('image_sort').value;

$.ajax({
    url: img_save_url ,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 20000,
    error: function() {
        alert('Error loading agent favorite property.');
    },
    success: function(html) {
        document.getElementById('sorted_successmsg_div').innerHTML = html;
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the script references are loading correctly?

Comment: It was loading correctly before i updated and now when i press button to save image order it appears 'processing...' and suddenly console show error.

Comment: I mean, run your site in chrome and hit F12 for the developer panel.  Check the resources tab and make sure jquery is loaded there.

Comment: Yeah, it's loaded there.

Comment: Can you try running some jQuery commands directly thought the console, see if that works